# writing a list of dataframes to file with lapply: How to paste object names to file names?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of dataframes:

```
lists <- replicate(10, as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)), simplify = FALSE)
names(lists) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

I want to write all dataframes to a separate file named according to their object name in R. I tried `lapply` with `paste`, but this horribly failed:

```
lapply(lists, function(x) write.table(x, file=paste(x,".txt"), sep="\t"))
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Called from: file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
```

How to do this without writing n single lines for n data.frames?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looping over the list elements, and not the names of the list elements. So the expression `paste(x,".txt")` tries to paste a `data.frame` to `.txt`, but you want to paste the name of the list element to `.txt`. So you can try the following:

```
lists <- replicate(10, as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)), simplify = FALSE)
names(lists) <- LETTERS[1:10]

lapply(names(lists), function(x) write.table(lists[[x]], file=paste(x,".txt"), sep="\t"))
```

To suppress the console output, wrap the statement in `invisible()`, or alternatively use a regular for-loop:

```
for (x in names(lists))
  write.table(lists[[x]], file=paste(x,".txt"), sep="\t")
```

Comment: The console output is confusing at first, but this is what i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @nouse, I agree that the console output is a bit confusing. I have added two options to prevent that from happening (if you were not familiar with those already.) Hope this helps!